# Converting ES6 code into ES5 (React/Javascript)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, if-statement, use-state

I'm struggling to convert the lines of code below into ES5 to make use of useState, useNavigate and other hooks as well. Also is there any proper technology out there that helps developers in converting ES5 to ES6 or vice versa?‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎

Any help/advice would be greatly appreciated! TIA

```
class Vote extends Component {
    state = {
        like: 0,
        dislike: 0,
        neutral: 0,
        likeActive: false,
        dislikeActive: false,
        neutralActive: false,
    };

    setDislike() {
        this.setState({
            dislikeActive: !this.state.dislikeActive,
            dislike: this.state.dislikeActive
                ? this.state.dislike - 1
                : this.state.dislike + 1
        });
    }
    setLike() {
        this.setState({
            likeActive: !this.state.likeActive,
            like: this.state.likeActive
                ? this.state.like - 1
                : this.state.like + 1
        });
    }

    setNeutral() {
        this.setState({
            neutralActive: !this.state.neutralActive,
            neutral: this.state.neutralActive
                ? this.state.neutral - 1
                : this.state.neutral + 1
        });
    }

    handleLike() {
        if (this.state.dislikeActive) {
            this.setLike();
            this.setDislike();
        } if (this.state.neutralActive) {
            this.setLike();
            this.setNeutral();
        }
        this.setLike();
    }

    handleDislike() {
        if (this.state.likeActive) {
            this.setDislike();
            this.setLike();
        } if (this.state.neutralActive) {
            this.setDislike();
            this.setNeutral();
        }
        this.setDislike();
    }

    handleNeutral() {
        if (this.state.dislikeActive) {
            this.setNeutral();
            this.setDislike();
        } if (this.state.likeActive) {
            this.setNeutral();
            this.setLike();
        }
        this.setNeutral();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <>
                <button onClick={() => this.handleLike()}>Plus: {this.state.like}</button>
                <button onClick={() => this.handleNeutral()}>Neutral:{this.state.neutral}</button>
                <button onClick={() => this.handleDislike()}>Minus: {this.state.dislike}</button>
            </>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Vote />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: This is a very confusing question. Why do you want to return to using ES5 to use hooks?

Comment: I'd like the user to navigate to another page when the state of the button is changed. I may be wrong but es6 classes doesn't seem to allow the usage of useNavigate hook in its components.